# Netbios adresses sometimes require .local sometimes .home - keeps changing, how to pick one?

Tags: network, macos

I have an annoying issue with several devices (mostly a mycloud NAS and a Raspberry Pi). I address them by their netbios name (like `mycloud.local`) and for days(?) it works fine - but every so often I encounter errors. For example Time Machine regularly complains it can't find the drive (although the notebook sits right next to the NAS and the WD app connects happily). Then for some time I need to correct into the other format (e.g. `mycloud.home`) and it will work for some time.

As you can imagine it gets tedious to adjust all the links.

Do you happen to know what might cause this switches and if there is a resolution? In case it matters I don't really care which extension the NetBIOS addresses finally use, as long as things stay consistent. I'm on a MacBook Pro with the latest Catalina (10.15.6).

*Addendum*

As pointed out NetBIOS may be the wrong protocol to blame. In the context of the question I intended to describe the self-assigned computer names in the local network (I got to the term reading up on how a Raspberry Pi sets its domain name.).

I'm having a suspicion it is my Mac producing the inconsistent names.  With the Pi I use the "USB gadget mode" (the Pi and the Mac are connected only through a USB cable which acts as network cable, no connection of the Pi with the rest of the network. It's off most of the time, only running an hour or so every other day when I play around). The router is very simplistic and doesn't appear to have any capabilities relating to netbios or bonjour. The NAS runs the unmodified version from WD, it has an option to act as 'Local Masterbrowser' for Windows services, I turn that on for now and see if anything changes. Besides that I only have "simpler" devices (phones, Apple TV, a printer) - can't be sure about them, but browsed their settings and so far didn't find anything that could be related.

*Update 2020-10-26*

Unfortunately the problem still persists. I have a new suspect - in my Access point configuration there is an option `Block LAN to WLAN Multicast and Broadcast Data` (with a longer help text explaining this should NEVER be disabled). Disabling it allowed me to again find my devices under the `.local` name. Though as my problem occurs only once every few weeks, I can not be sure if this is a fix.

Comment: Why do think it is the netbios name? I would have thought the bonjour name. Do you have a windows or unix machine acting as a nameserver

Comment: One of the devices on your network is acting as a "master browser" EG is handing out network names using one or the other suffixes (.local or .home) you need to go through ALL of them (NAS, Router, computers) and validate the settings so that they are all the same.

Comment: Could be bonjour name, I came to the netbios reading up how the raspi got its name.

Comment: Good suggestion. The Pi is in USB gadget mode, without network forward so I am not sure what other machine could be involved. For the other devices - i don't see any settings about this on my router. besides the nas it's just phones and apple tv - how could I find out if one of them is acting as master?

Comment: I have a NAS but not a mycloud so I cannot test myself: is your TimeMachine connecting using AFP or SMB? Can you disable AFP on the NAS and connect using only SMB?

Comment: There’s a free macOS application called Discover that shows Bonjour services advertised on your network. I use it regularly to check network issues.

Comment: @GeorgesMartin I can connect like this, but unfortunately Time Machine won't accept the NAS when I mount it as SMB. Anyway I feel this is only tangentially related - the NAS show up correctly eg. in the Finder sidebar, however the bookmarks (and Time Machine) stop working and need to be altered when it transitions from `.local` to `.home` or back.